# Aplication of Hahn-Banach theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, dual-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

Consider the measurable space $([0,1],\mathcal{B}([0,1]),l)$, where $\mathcal{B}([0,1])$ denotes the Borel algebra in $[0,1]$ and $l$ is the Lebesgue measure.

I need to prove that exists a bounded linear functional $\Gamma\neq 0$ over $L_{\infty}$ which vanishes over $\mathcal{C}([0,1]).$ Conclude that $(L_\infty)^{*}\neq L_{1}.$ The suggestion is to consider the subspace of bounded functions which admits limit in the origin, and apply the Hahn-Banach theorem.

**Hahn-Banach Theorem:** Let $V$ a  real vector space and $p:V\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$ an application satisfying $p(cv)=cp(v)$ and $p(u+v)\leq p(u)+p(v)$  for any $c>0$ and $u,v\in V.$ Suppose that $\gamma:W\rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ is a linear functional  over an vector subspace $W\subset V$ satisfying $\gamma(w)\leq p(w)$ for all $w\in W.$ So, $\gamma$ extends to a linear functional $\Gamma$ defined over all $V$ satisfying $\Gamma(v)\leq p(v)$ for any $v\in V.$

Looks like the question is not that hard, but I'm confused about how to apply the theorem for this case.

My function $p$ needs to be a function from $[0,1]$ to $\Bbb{R}$, right? And it needs to satisfies that $\gamma(x)\leq p(x)$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ for some linear functional $\gamma:W\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$. My first question is, what is $W$ in my example? Doesn't make sense $W$ be the set of all bounded functions such that exists limit in $0$, since all the functions in $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$  satisfies this. I need  to take $W$ as a subspace of $\mathcal{C}[(0,1)]$ or $L_{\infty}?$

You can see that I'm really confused, so if someone could help me patiently, would help me.

Comment: When we say $X^{\ast}=Y$ that means $L(f)=\displaystyle\int fg$ for some $g\in Y$. So you are to prove that there is no such integral representation for such a linear functional. I indeed have a solution, but it looks rather complicated, I used mollifier or some sort. I am waiting for elementary solution as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick an $f_{0}\in L^{\infty}-C[0,1]$ and let $W=\text{span}(\{f_{0}\}\cup C[0,1])$. Consider $\Gamma(\alpha f_{0}+g)=\alpha d(f_{0},C[0,1])$ for any scalar $\alpha$, then $\Gamma$ vanishes on $C[0,1]$, certainly $\Gamma$ is a non-zero bounded linear functional on $W$.

Hahn-Banach Theorem gives an extension of $\Gamma$ to the whole $L^{\infty}$.

Comment: What does means $d(f_{0},C[0,1])?$

Comment: The distance from $f_{0}$ to $C[0,1]$.

Comment: How do you define distance from a function to a set of functions? The infimum of distances $d(f_0,f)$ where $f\in C[0,1]$ ?

Comment: Yes, taking the infimum of it.

Comment: Just to be sure.
The distance of functions $d$ that you are using is the distance generated by the norm $||\cdot ||_\infty$ ? That is, the infimum of $d(f,g)=\inf_{x\in[0,1]} |f(x)-g(x)|$ ?

Comment: No, it is $\inf\{\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f_{0}(x)-h(x)|: h\in C[0,1]\}$.

Comment: Sorry for insist, but I want to know the details, hehe.
The distance between two functions $f,g$ is defined by $\tilde{d}(f,g)=\inf_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|$, right?

Comment: If you want to be compatible with the metric (distance) induced by the norm of $C[0,1]$, it should be $d(f,g)=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|$.

Comment: Thanks for all your help!
Just one more question, please.

I need to conclude that $(L_{\infty})^{*}\neq L_{1}$. That assertion is not making sense to me, since the set $(L_{\infty})^{*}$ is a space of functionals $F:L_\infty\rightarrow \Bbb{R}$, and $L_1$ is a space of functions $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \Bbb{R}.$ How can I compare this sets?